# Spring Application Context: How do you set a constructor argument of a class to a class static member variable?

Tags: spring, static-members, applicationcontext, restlet-2.0

In the application context XML file, how do you set a constructor argument to a static class member?

For example, I am using Restlet and one of Restlet's classes called ChallengeAuthenticator receives a challenge scheme member variable.

```
// Normal Initialization
ChallengeAuthenticator challengeAuthenticator = new ChallengeAuthenticator(
                null, ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "WSRealm");
```

I want to have this in the application context if possible. To something like this:

```
<bean id="challengeAuthenticator" class="org.restlet.security.ChallengeAuthenticator">
  <!-- Not meant to be String for value just trying to make it easier to reader to interpret my question -->  
  <constructor-arg value="ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Spring Expression Language](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

```
<constructor-arg value="#{ T(ChallengeScheme).HTTP_BASIC }" />
```

Note that you need a full class name in `T(...)`.